# How can I go to history.back() when page loads?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP page that has an error, but if I go back, it works fine.
I can't redirect because the page can be accessed from two different places.

How can I make a JavaScript that loads automatically when the page loads?

Thanks,
Sebastian

**EDIT**

that wouldn't work.
is there a way to get the url of history.go(-2)?

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: I don't really understand. Wouldn't it be more sensible to fix the error in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
<body onload="history.go(-1);">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the window's onload property is that you do not want the user to wait for the current page to load.  Just put this code/HTML at the top of the page right after the opening `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">history.go(-1);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`window.history` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history), like this:

```
history.back();
//or:
history.go(-1);
```

Comment: @sebastian are you asking if you can call this function in PHP? If so, No - No You can't

Comment: Doesn't your PHP script generate plain HTML?

Comment: @sebastian - If it's in a script block, yes it'll work...I'm still unclear on your exact usage though, why not redirect to the referrer in PHP (with a header)?